# Publishing T-SQL procedures to multiple databases

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a collection of SQL Server batch procedures, all of which need to get installed, and periodically executed, they all have the following structure:

USE

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
  DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE

AS

BEGIN

<...Procedure body...>

END

I'm looking for a way to run each .sql file once to install it on all the databases. The procedures are long, so recopying them multiple times each with a separate USE statement is not practical, and is also difficult to maintain.

I tried using a cursor on sys.databases with USE @DB_Name but that did not work, because USE does not accept parameters, and because CREATE PROCEDURE needs to be the first statement in a block.

Any help or direction will be greatly appreciated.

---

So I ended up using WrathOfKhan's solution, for everyone's benefit, here is how this was implemented.

1. Created blank results.log file.
2. Created CreatProcs.Bat file, as follows:

```
@echo off
```

echo Session start %date% %time%
echo Session start %date% %time% >> results.log

REM The first file contains the DDL to create related tables, etc. 
REM all the subsequent files are my procs. U and P switches  are omitted, 
REM since this file runs from a permissioned account.

sqlcmd -b -S %1 -d %2 -i file1.sql >> results.log 
sqlcmd -b -S %1 -d %2 -i file2.sql >> results.log
...

echo Session end %date% %time%
echo Session end %date% %time% >> results.log

1. Created PublishAll.bat

```
CreateProcs DBServerName Database1
CreateProcs DBServerName Database2
CreateProcs DBServerName Database3
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you generate the script files without the USE?

Comment: No, I need to publish to multiple databases, how can I do so without a USE statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write the script without the USE and then run it using SqlCmd and specifying the database using the -d flag. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx)

```
sqlcmd -U username -P password -d db1 -i myscript.sql
sqlcmd -U username -P password -d db2 -i myscript.sql
sqlcmd -U username -P password -d db3 -i myscript.sql
sqlcmd -U username -P password -d db4 -i myscript.sql
```